# how to get the values as below: 1 A 000000000001548 000000000000458

Tags: sql, sybase

how to get the values as below:

I want the result as "countervalue,sp_value"
what I tried is

```
select product id,name,
CASE WHEN PLAN = '0' then Replicate('0', 16 - LEN(AM_COUNTERVALUE)) + AM_COUNTERVALUE else '000000000000000' END AS COUNTERVALUE
CASE WHEN IS_SAVING_PLAN = '1' then Replicate('0', 16 - LEN(AM_COUNTERVALUE)) + AM_COUNTERVALUE else '000000000000000' END AS SP_VALUE
into tmp from #temp

select product id,name,COUNTERVALUE+SP_VALUE
from tmp
```

its output like

```
1 A 000000000001548 000000000000000
1 A 000000000000000 000000000000458
```

but expected output is

```
1 A 000000000001548 000000000000458
```

could you help me out

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Sybase? (Rare combination...)

Comment: This is not Oracle code

Comment: Sybase @DuduMarkovitz

Answer (score 1):

You need a `group by`:

```
select product as id, name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PLAN = '0' then Replicate('0', 16 - LEN(AM_COUNTERVALUE)) + AM_COUNTERVALUE else '000000000000000' END) AS COUNTERVALUE
       MAX(CASE WHEN IS_SAVING_PLAN = '1' then Replicate('0', 16 - LEN(AM_COUNTERVALUE)) + AM_COUNTERVALUE else '000000000000000' END) AS SP_VALUE
from #temp
group by product, name;
```